# Import external component and loose reactivity in vue3

Tags: html, vue.js, components, vue-component, vuejs3

I have 2 projects/folders (with Lerna on the root).

The first one is uicomponents with some components and the second one is testing a simple app which uses some component from uicomponents.

I created a simple counter component (Counter.vue) :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Total clicks: {{ count }}</h3>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button class="inc" @click.prevent="increment">Add</button>
      <button class="dec" @click.prevent="decrement">Subtract</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Counter',
  props: {
    startingNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const count = ref(props.startingNumber);
    const increment = () => {
      count.value += 1;
      alert(count.value);
    };
    const decrement = () => {
      count.value -= 1;
    };
    return {
      count,
      increment,
      decrement,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

And I import it in my app on a simple page :

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <counter :starting-number="5"></counter>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import Counter from '@uicomponents/counter';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components: {
    Counter,
  },
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'Me',
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Lerna correctly replace all my components path and I retrieve my components Counter in my pages with all HTML. Buttons works well and my alert are displays with the correct value BUT my html are not refreshed.

This text `<h3>Total clicks: {{ count }}</h3>` stay "Total clicks: 0". My "count" ref is well updated because the alert displayed it correct but not in html.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with lost reactivity. My setup is a bit different, but in the end it's the same result.

I'm trying to build a small plugin system which loads external components
Roughly I try to do this

```
// pluginSystem.js is accessible through window.myps
// ...
init(app) {
    vueApp = app;
},
// ...
loadPlugin(data) {
    vueApp.component(data.component.name, data.component);
}
```

And my external component looks like this

```
// main.js
import Counter from './components/Counter.vue';

window.myps.loadPlugin({
    component: Counter,
});
```

Button click in counter, etc. works, console logging is fine as well, but component data is not updated.
I also tried defineComponent and defineAsyncComponent, but as you I had no luck with it...

Comment: I could track my problem down to composition api. Usimg `import {reactive} from 'vue'` results in a seperate copy of vue in the plugin. There are several solutions like "add vue as dev/peerDependencies" in package.json or define vue as external in webpack config. But unfortunately, both solutions didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    import { defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent } from "vue"
```

```
components: {         
      Counter:defineAsyncComponent(() => import("@uicomponents/counter"))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I have already tried and it does not work. I tried to put my COunter.vue components in the same folder of my applications and its works... Its strange.. Maybe a problems with Lerna ?